# passing a variable in a redirect

Tags: php, variables, redirect

I have been at this for over 10 man hours now and Im not getting closer. Unfortunately my php skills are very rusty and theres been changes. 
I am using the geo ip dat file and inc to redirect based on visitors country.
When the visitor clicks the original link, an aff id for the site they came from is passed 
/index.php?affid=somevariableid
the index page then determines the country and then I want to pass the affid and the country code to the "someurl" destination with those two variables.

**UPDATE**
The following prints the correct value for affid and country_code to the page but it is not passing in the link so the resulting link has no variables to pull.

```
    require_once("geoip.inc");

    $gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

    $country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    geoip_close($gi);
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "GET" && $_REQUEST['affid'] != '' ){
    $affid = $_GET['affid'];
    //echo $affid;
    }
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "GET" && $country_code != '' ){
    $ctry = $country_code;
    //echo $country_code;
    }
if($country_code == 'GB')
{
        header('Location: someurl?affid='.$affid.'&c='.$ctry);
}

else {
        header('Location: someurl?affid='.$affid.'&c='.$ctry);
```

Comment: If `$country_code` can only have one value, why aren't you just hardcoding it in? `header('Location: someurl?c=US&affid={affid}');`

Comment: header('Location: someurl?affid='.$_GET['affid']);

Comment: The country of the visitor can be dynamic hence the redirection based on ip. Also putting the get affid in the url doesnt pass anything, I think I have to pull the affid on that page and then pass it again in the new url. which brings me back to the country code. how do I assign the variable to a string to pass it in the url?

Comment: I basically want to take $country_code and pass it in the C variable in the url

Comment: ahh John I see where your question came from, the us redirect link has the country code and gb doesnt because I was testing with a us IP and wanted to get it working there first before inserting it into the gb and all others links.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `{affid}` with `'.$_GET['affid'].'`

Answer (score 0):

Think you need double quotes too, header("Location: blah ");

Comment: hi nk, everything else is working fine with the single quotes that came with the original rediret script.

Comment: tried changing to dble quotes and all it did was give an error on the else statement